# Black Login Screen after installing updates 12.04

Tags: updates, login-screen

Yesterday my 12.04 installed new updates and I clicked on restart.

GRUB loaded normally, but then instead of my pretty desktop (auto login turned on) I got a black screen asking for login and password.

Why? How can I get my desktop back to before?

This is due to updates I am sure, nothing in hardware has changed and no other display settings changed... using AMD driver from their site for my raedeon 6850 and have catalyst driver working fine.

I have tried typing in commands like `sudo start lightdm`
and `sudo startx` these didn't do anything - just froze.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your solution but it didn't seem to work. I removed my fglrx driver by the following command:

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
```

And then my desktop came back after reboot. Then reinstalled ATI catalyst driver. Now, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

in that black screen, login with your username and password, and install gdm

```
sudo apt-get install gdm
```

that might solve the problem, I also had same problem when I did some things with my installation..

Comment: hi..thanks so much for replying.. ok will that restore it..i appreciate it thankyou :)

Comment: if that doesn't work (as indicated by some other source, try  `sudo apt-get install lightdm` (gdm _might_ have problem in 12.*)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with Black Opal which is based on 12.04. Also switching to tty8 then tty7 seems to get you to the login screen with lightdm installed. I switched to gdm and the problems is gone, I just don't like how it changed the login screen to the old look...
ctrl+alt+f8
ctrl+alt+f7